# Malformed Line 61 (dist parse) ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu

I run sudo apt-get update but it returns:

E: Malformed line 61 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

I opened the sources.list via vim /etc/apt/sources.list

and Line 61 is : deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal partner

How can I correct this as I cannot install even software center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line (and the line before it) should be:

```
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
```

It is not a partner repository, it is a main respoitory.